# Grails Spring Security: Switching between dual ROLEs

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

In my project certain users have dual roles, so if any such user logs in how can I make him switch between those 2 ROLES he has so that he can perform certain operations which that particular ROLE provides.

Appreciate step by step process as I am really new to Grails. Any such literature online with example is highly appreciated.

UPDATE:- 
WorkridersUser loadUserByUsername(String username, String roleName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        //Class User = grailsApplication.getDomainClass("Person").clazz

```
    SchemeUser.withTransaction { status ->

        SchemeUser user = SchemeUser.findByUsername(username) 
        if (!user){ throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)}

        UserProfile userProfile = UserProfile.findByEmail(user.username)
        Representative representative = Representative.findByUser(user)
        Organization organization = Organization.get(representative.organization.id)


        def authorities = user.authorities.collect {new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority)}

        return new WorkridersUser(user.username, user.password, user.enabled, 
            !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired, !user.accountLocked, 
            authorities ?: roleName, user.id, organization.companyName,userProfile) 
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Sri

Comment: Burt Beckwith, I am looking forward to your reply ;)

Comment: If user have two roles, that means that she already have access to both operations, why you need to switch between roles?

Comment: e.g. I have these roles, Employer,Employee and a Representative. Since Employer cannot act himself he needs a Representative on its behalf. But Representative is also an Employee of that particular Employer, so I want to switch between Representative & Employee types of roles. When logged in as Representative he can approve or reject certain transactions, but being an Employee he doesnt have that capability. Hence I needed to switch. Appreciate any idea how to implement this

Comment: is she having both roles at *same* time?

Comment: I can't understand this problem. If your user have Employer role - it have access to resources for this role, if she have role Representative - access to representative resources. As she have both roles at same time - she have access to any of this resource, at same time. Isn't it?

Comment: i mean: isn't it working out of box?

Comment: Currently I can display both the functionalities applicable to both the roles together, but I want to separate that, I want if he chooses to ACT as an Representative he sees only screens applicable to Representative ROLE. If he chooses to be just an Employee he sees screens applicable for that ROLE not of Representative. I hope you got my point this time

Comment: @splix let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1695/discussion-between-srisris-and-splix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override the loadUserByUsername method as follows:

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, String selectedRole) {
  // current selected role is stored in the member variable of the UserDetail class         
  this.selectedRole = selectedRole
  return loadUserByUsername(username)
}
```

to show all roles of current user within a select box write your own tag lib which should look like:

```
def authorities = springSecurityService.principal.originalAuthorities
if (authorities.size() > 1) {
    out << "<form name='switchRoleForm' action='switchRole' method='post'>"
    out << "<select name='roles'>"
    Role tmpRole
    authorities.each {
        tmpRole = Role.findByAuthority(it.authority)
        // access your current select role
            if (springSecurityService.principal.selectedRole== it.authority)
            out << "<option selected value='${it.authority}'>${tmpRole.name}</option>"
        else
            out << "<option value='${it.authority}'>${tmpRole.name}</option>"
    }
    out << "</select>"
    out << '<input class="switch" type="submit" value="switch"/></span>'
    out << "</form>"        
}
```

i described the switch logic in previous post.

Answer (score 2):

first of all you have to implement your own user details class and serivce. http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html. Within your own UserDetailsService you can motify the authorities property in the loadUserByUsername method, so that this property contains only one role at the same time. then you can switch between roles by modifying this property agian. for example

```
// imagine the following code would be in your switch controller action
// fetch your user detail service bean (registered via resources.groovy and not as a service)
UserDetailsService userDetailsService = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("userDetailsService");
UserCache userCache = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("userCache");
// update authorities in user details. only one role should exists in authorities list
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username, <place here the rolel to switch>);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(),userDetails.getAuthorities()));
// refresh user detail
userCache.removeUserFromCache(springSecurityService.principal.username);
```

Comment: How will my UserDetails class look like.

Comment: Also can you let me know how you implemented that UserCache?

Comment: sorry, i have forgotten to post the chapter where you can find the explaination to implement your custom user detail service. see http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html chapter 11 Custom UserDetailsService. you don't need to implent the user cache, because this is a spring security bean. the user detail service provides a method called "loadUserByUsername". there you can modify the authorities property i described above.

Comment: Thank you hitty5(hoping thats your realname). Your hint put me in the right direction. Appreciate it again

Comment: can you please accept or vote up my answer, depending on you satisfaction.

Comment: Do I need to have a dropdown list with different authorities so that user with dual roles can switch. How did you handle the front end part. Also in my RoleSwitchController you mentioned that I need to update authorities, how to do that? Little more help please

Comment: you can fetch all roles of user by calling springSecurityService.principal.originalAuthorities. this collection can be used for displaying the roles in a select. then the user can select a role by name and with this name you can update the authorities property of your user detail class, as i described in my code example before

Comment: Hi Hitty5, can you share with me code for loadUserByUsername method.My implementation for the same method is not working. I updated my code in the original description of issue